# PHP image file upload uppecase extension problem

Tags: php, image, upload

I've a php script to deal with uploaded images.

it works fine if i upload a file like file.jpg.

But i got trouble if i try to upload file.JPG. Even if its the same file renamed.

The code:

```
if(isset($_FILES["arq"])){ 
    @getimagesize($_FILES['arq']['tmp_name']) or $err=5; 
    ($_FILES['arq']['error']==0) or $err=$_FILES['arq']['error'];


    if ($err==0){
        $dir = "./img/".$_SESSION['estudante']."/";
        if (!is_dir($dir)){mkdir($dir);}
        $filename = substr(md5(uniqid(rand(), true)),0,20) . ".";
        $filename .= pathinfo($_FILES["arq"]["name"], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        $fotourl = $dir . basename($filename);//$_FILES["arq"]["name"]);
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["arq"]["tmp_name"], $fotourl);
        //resize e cira thumbnails
        resizeimg($fotourl, 320,204);   //editfoto
        resizeimg($fotourl, 137,87);    //album
        resizeimg($fotourl, 200,0);     //home
        resizeimg($fotourl, 148,0);     //perfil
        resizeimg($fotourl, 60,60);     //thumbnail
        resizeimg($fotourl, 100,0);     //iframe perfil
        resizeimg($fotourl, 530, 530);  //slide
        resizeimg($fotourl, 330, 0);    //i slide
        //registra no BD
        $sql="INSERT INTO fotos (estudante, url) VALUES ('".$_SESSION['estudante']."', '$fotourl')";
        mysql_query($sql);
        //retorna o id da foto
        $fotoid=mysql_insert_id();
        //notifica adms somente
        $sql="select estudante from administradores";
        $adms=mysql_query($sql);
        while ($ar=mysql_fetch_assoc($adms)){
            $msg="O usuário <a href=\"perfil.php?id=$_SESSION[estudante]\">".nomeapelido($_SESSION['estudante'])."</a> inseriu uma nova <a href='fotoslide.php?fotoid=$fotoid'>imagem</a>.";
            $sql="insert into mensagens (msgde, msgpara, msgmsg) values (5, $ar[estudante], '$msg')";   // 5=cadastro do 'user' sistema
            mysql_query($sql);
            //echo "$sql\n";
        }
        mysql_free_result($adms);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by 'got Trouble'? What kind of trouble? Error messages?

Comment: `$_FILES['arq']['error']==0` ?  Seriously?  I didn't piss and moan for them to make the PHP upload errors into constants just for people to hard code them. >:/

Comment: The 'trouble' is that it only creates a small image with 60x60px. All ohter sizes aren't created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to just rename the extension to lower case when you move the file. If it's really important to preserve the actual case of the extension of the initial file, it is easy enough to store it in a variable before strtolower is applied, pass it into the imgresize function, and use that for the extension when the resized img is saved.

```
$filename .= strtolower(pathinfo($_FILES["arq"]["name"], PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
$fotourl = $dir . basename($filename);//$_FILES["arq"]["name"]);
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["arq"]["tmp_name"], $fotourl);
```